# Delete leaf nodes with single relationship in neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to remove leaf nodes in Neo4j, but only those with a single incoming relationship.  (I'm so close.)

I have a query that returns the exact node I wish to remove.  However, when I replace the RETURN with DELETE, it removes more than the query returns.  Here's the complete sequence:

```
neo4j-sh (?)$ match (n)-[r]->(p)  return n, r, p ;
+------------------------------------------------------------+
| n                    | r            | p                    |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
| Node[2164]{name:"a"} | :has[2616]{} | Node[2165]{name:"b"} |
| Node[2164]{name:"a"} | :has[2617]{} | Node[2166]{name:"c"} |
| Node[2166]{name:"c"} | :has[2619]{} | Node[2168]{name:"e"} |
| Node[2167]{name:"d"} | :has[2618]{} | Node[2165]{name:"b"} |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
```

This query is perfect:

```
neo4j-sh (?)$ match ()-[r:has]->(n)
>   with n,count(r) as rel_cnt
>   where rel_cnt = 1 and NOT (n)-->()
>   return n.name, rel_cnt;
+------------------+
| n.name | rel_cnt |
+------------------+
| "e"    | 1       |
+------------------+
```

But this delete removed 2 nodes and 3 relationships?

```
neo4j-sh (?)$ match ()-[r:has]->(n)
>   with n, r, count(r) as rel_cnt
>   where rel_cnt = 1 and NOT (n)-->()
>   delete n, r;
+-------------------+
| No data returned. |
+-------------------+
Nodes deleted: 2
Relationships deleted: 3
```

This is all that's left

```
neo4j-sh (?)$ match (n)-[r]->(p)  return n, r, p ;
+------------------------------------------------------------+
| n                    | r            | p                    |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
| Node[2164]{name:"a"} | :has[2617]{} | Node[2166]{name:"c"} |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
neo4j-sh (?)$ match (n) return n;
+----------------------+
| n                    |
+----------------------+
| Node[2169]{name:"a"} |
| Node[2171]{name:"c"} |
| Node[2172]{name:"d"} |
+----------------------+
```

Why was node 'b' removed?  It didn't show in the query results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The queries are actually not identical even apart from `RETURN/DELETE`. The return query carries `n, count(r)` to the second query part, the delete query carries `n, r, count(r)`. Try returning the delete query to see that, i.e. run this

```
neo4j-sh (?)$ match ()-[r:has]->(n)
>   with n, r, count(r) as rel_cnt
>   where rel_cnt = 1 and NOT (n)-->()
//>   delete n, r;
>   return *;
```

and you'll get something like

```
+-----------------------------------------------+
| n                    | r            | rel_cnt |
+-----------------------------------------------+
| Node[2165]{name:"b"} | :has[2616]{} | 1       |
| Node[2165]{name:"b"} | :has[2618]{} | 1       |
| Node[2168]{name:"e"} | :has[2619]{} | 1       |
+-----------------------------------------------+
```

The reason for the different result is that piping `n, count(r)` means something like "count r per n", and there is only one case where "count r per n = 1". But the other pipe means something like "count r per n and per r" and if you count or group something by itself, then it's going to be one every time. The reason something is *not* deleted is that it was never matched or is excluded by the other filter critera (`NOT (n)-->()`), the `rel_cnt=1` is rendered useless.

---

If you want to first count the relationships and then conditionally delete them, you can collect them, filter on collection size, and then delete from the collection. Try something like

```
MATCH ()-[r:has]->(n)
WITH n, collect(r) as rr
WHERE length(rr) = 1 AND NOT n-->()
FOREACH (r IN rr | DELETE r)
DELETE n
```

Comment: Wow, thanks jjaderberg!  That was not apparent to me,  I'm still trying to grok the 'with' clause.  Your explanation is a big help.