# NEO4j Cypher query to return paths with a condition on the number of connected nodes

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I would like to clean up my graph database a bit by removing unnecessary nodes.  In one case, unnecessary nodes are nodes B between nodes A and C where B has the same name as node C and NO OTHER incoming relationships.  I am having trouble coming up with a Cypher query that restricts the number of incoming edges.

The first part was easy:

```
MATCH (n1:TypeA)<-[r1:Inside]-(n2:TypeB)<-[r2:Inside]-(n3:TypeC)
WHERE n2.name = n3.name
```

Based on other SE questions (especially [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22999055/delete-leaf-nodes-with-single-relationship-in-neo4j)) I then tried doing something like:

```
WITH n2, collect(r2) as rr
WHERE length(rr) = 1 
RETURN n2
```

but this also returned nodes with more than one incoming edge.  It seems my `WHERE` clause on the length is not filtering the returned `n2` nodes.  I tried a few other things I found online, but they either returned nothing or were no 
longer syntactically correct in the current version.

After I find the `n2` nodes that match the pattern, I'll want to connect `n3` directly to `n1` and `DETACH DELETE n2`.  Again, I was easily able to do that part when I didn't need the restriction on the number of incoming edges to `n2`.  That previous question has `FOREACH (r IN rr | DELETE r)`, but I want to detach delete the `n2` nodes, not just those edges. I don't know how to correctly adapt this to operating on the nodes attached to the `r`s and I certainly want to be sure it's finding the correct nodes before deleting anything since Neo4j lacks basic undo functionality (but you can't put a `RETURN` command inside a `FOREACH` for some crazy reason).

> How do I filter nodes on a path by the number of incoming edges using Cypher?

I think I can do this in py2neo by first collecting all the `n1,n2,n3` triples matching the pattern, then going through each returned record and add them to a list if `n2` has only one incoming edge.  Then go through that list and perform the trimming operation, but if this can be done in pure Cypher, then I'd like to know how because I have a number of similar adjustments to make.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass along `path` in your `WITH` statement.

```
MATCH path = (n1:Ward)<-[r1:PARTOF]-(n2:Unknown)<-[r2:PARTOF]-(n3:Chome)
WHERE n2.name = n3.name
WITH path, size((n2)<-[:PARTOF]-()) as degree
WHERE degree = 1
RETURN path
```

Or shorter like this:

```
MATCH path = (n1:Ward)<-[r1:PARTOF]-(n2:Unknown)<-[r2:PARTOF]-(n3:Chome)
WHERE n2.name = n3.name
AND size((n2)<-[:PARTOF]-()) = 1
RETURN path
```

Comment: Restricting the in-degree directly using a `WHERE` condition is the most intuitive to me.  I tried several things like that, including the above code using collect, based on the examples and documentation I could find, but I had no idea it could be used directly like that.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Borrowing some insight from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32775427/how-to-get-degree-of-a-node-while-filtering-using-match-in-neo4j) I came up with a kludge that seems to work.

```
MATCH path = (n1:Ward)<-[r1:PARTOF]-(n2:Unknown)<-[r2:PARTOF]-(n3:Chome)
WHERE n2.name = n3.name
WITH n2, size((n2)<-[:PARTOF]-()) as degree
WHERE degree = 1
MATCH (n1:Ward)<-[r1:PARTOF]-(n2:Unknown)<-[r2:PARTOF]-(n3:Chome)
RETURN n1,n2,n3
```

I expect that not all parts of that are needed and it isn't an efficient solution, but I don't know enough yet to improve upon it.

For example, I define the first line as `path`, but I can't use `MATCH path` in the penultimate line, and I have no idea why.

Also, if I write `WITH size((n2)<-[:PARTOF]-()) as degree` (dropping the `n2,` after WITH) it returns not only the `n2` with degree > 1, but also all the nodes connected to them (even more than the `n3` nodes).  I don't know why it behaves like this and the Neo4j documentation for WITH has no examples or description to help me understand why the `n2` is necessary here.  Any improvements to my Cypher query or explanation of *how* or *why* it works would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You didn't pass along `path` in your `WITH` statement.

Comment: That's true, my attempts to use path anywhere else (after defining it) didn't return the correct thing...actually the code above returns the correct subgraphs if I leave the `path=` part out.  And it works with `n2,` in there instead of `path`, but it clearly needs one or the other, and I have no idea why that is necessary.  Nothing like that appears in the documentation and none of the examples I've seen come with explanations.